# How to populate data in a excel sheet with VBA code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vba, spreadsheet

We are trying to create an excel document which supports macros with some data validation code. 
Is it possible to use `axlsx` package to create such a document.

e.g. A single sheet called Users which contains a `VBA script` (which can be viewed using Sheet --> View Code)

We could also provide a simple xls template file with this information, would it be possible to add rows with column data using axlsx gem.

Comment: This is a very broad question outside the scope of a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, the answer is yes but as Brettdj said this is a broad guestion. I think you should first [read this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s8p1.html) and [this](http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html) about creating forms. and then reffer to these links:

[how-do-i-set-data-validation-in-vba](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/559023-how-do-i-set-data-validation-in-vba.html)

[visual-basic-applications-validation-rule](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/453307-visual-basic-applications-validation-rule.html)

Reviewing these addresses will help you to understand exactly what is possible and what is not.